# Loading Ordered (Synchronous) HTML Content with Asynchronous JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, synchronous

I have separate HTML files containing small bits of content which are loaded using AJAX and .get(). I want to be able to display ordered content *without* using `async: false` in my AJAX call, as this method is deprecated. As the site grows, I am also concerned that the synchronous JavaScript will be detrimental to performance.

I have access to an array filled with a complete list of filenames. Typically, these ought to be displayed in alphanumerical order based on filename; however, I do need to manipulate the order in certain circumstances. I hope to accomplish this by simply manipulating the array.

Currently, I accomplish loading and displaying this "ordered content" by sorting the array and using `async: false` in the AJAX call.

```
function loadOrderedContent(divID, directory) {
/* populate_index.php JSON query must exist in directory */

    /* empty any previous div content */
    $('#' + divID).empty();

    $.get(directory + 'populate_index.php', function(logindex) {

        /* parse populate_index.php and determine length */
        var decoded_logindex = JSON.parse(logindex);
        var size = decoded_logindex.length;

        /* remove ".." and "." from end of decoded_logindex */
        decoded_logindex.splice(size - 2, 2)
        size = decoded_logindex.length;

        /* NOTE: This is where I manipulate array */
        // ~~array manipulation function(s)~~

        /* populate div with ordered content */
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (decoded_logindex[i] != 'populate_index.php') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: directory + decoded_logindex[i],
                    async: false, // <<== I don't want this anymore
                    success: function(data) {
                        /* append HTML content to desired div */
                        $('#' + divID).append(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Synchronous AJAX request failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This gives me the desired results. However, if I use an asynchronous solution (to avoid deprecation), the div is haphazardly filled as HTML content loads.

Comment: Would it be OK for everything to be appended at once, once all requests are complete?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, as long as everything was in the order I specified in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to wait for all responses to come back, and once they do, you'll have an array in the order of the original `decoded_logindex`, and you can append everything at once:

```
const proms = decoded_logindex
  .filter(str => str !== 'populate_index.php')
  .map(str => $.ajax(directory + str));
Promise.all(proms)
  .then((dataArr) => {
    const $elm = $('#' + divID);
    dataArr.forEach((data) => {
      $elm.append(data);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    alert("Request failed");
  });
```

Alternatively, if you want a failed request to not result in the whole process failing, you might append an error string instead, by `catch`ing the `$.ajax` instead of `catch`ing the `Promise.all`:

```
const proms = decoded_logindex
  .filter(str => str !== 'populate_index.php')
  .map(str => (
    $.ajax(directory + str)
    .catch(() => '<span>Error fetching ' + str + '</span>')
  ));
Promise.all(proms)
  .then((dataArr) => {
    const $elm = $('#' + divID);
    dataArr.forEach((data) => {
      $elm.append(data);
    });
  })
```